Why is my Github Action Composer authentication failing intermittently?
I am installing my Composer dependencies within a Github Action and it works perfectly fine. However, from time to time I keep getting Could not authenticate against github.com authentication errors.
I am aware that Github has API rate limits and needs authentication via a personal access token. My Github Action looks like this:
  - name: Install Composer dependencies
    run: |
      composer config --global github-oauth.github.com "${{ secrets.TOKEN }}"
      composer install -n --prefer-dist

Everytime I update my Github Action YAML file, Composer runs perfectly fine for a couple of days but it keeps failing intermittently afterwards. I tried a million ways to authorize Composer against Github already. What am I missing here?
